# Spark Streaming Kinesis partition key and sequence number log in java

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

We are using spark 2.4.3 in java. We would like to log the partition key and the sequence number of every event. The overloaded create stream function
of the kinesis utils always throws a compilation error.

```
Function<Record,Record> printSeq = s -> s;
KinesisUtils.createStream(
  jssc,
  appName,
  streamName,
  endPointUrl,
  regionName,
  InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON,
  kinesisCheckpointInterval,
  StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER(),
  printSeq,
  Record.class);
```

The exception is as follows:

> no suitable method found for
>   createStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream,org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration,org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel,java.util.function.Function,java.lang.Class)

JAVA DOCS : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kinesis/KinesisUtils.html#createStream-org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream-org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration-org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function-java.lang.Class-

Is there a way out?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, ```Function<Record,Record> printSeq = s -> s;``` is the definition. Also, I tried adding ```scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Record.class);``` also in the function call to create stream function. This is the FQN of the record class ```com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record```

Comment: No idea. Sorry.